# Cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, centos, wildfly

I am using

```
SpringBoot 3.1.0
Java 17
Wildfly 28.0.1
CentOS 9
```

I can able to build the portal without any error in eclipse
[image]

I have successfully deployed my SpringBoot application to wildfly.
[image]

But when I access the url,
e.g. http://localhost:8080/myportal

It is showing an error page
[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>myportal</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myportal</name>
    <description>Our Backoffice</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.hazendaz</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlcompressor</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>js</artifactId>
                    <groupId>rhino</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JavaScript optimizing compiler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.javascript</groupId>
            <artifactId>closure-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>v20221102</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

> Error processing request Context Path:/myportal Servlet Path:/error
> Path Info:null Query String:null Stack Trace:
> jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class jakarta.servlet.http.MappingMatch
> cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping
> (jakarta.servlet.http.MappingMatch and
> jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping are in unnamed module of
> loader 'jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0' @2d839aa7)     at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1019)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
> at
> jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
> at
> jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
> at
> org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@3.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
> at
> org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
> at
> org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
> at
> org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)  at
> org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@3.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:258)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:183)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:188)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:136)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:99)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:189)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:174)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:141)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:99)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
> at
> org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@3.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
> at
> org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
> at
> org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
> at
> org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)  at
> org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@3.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
> at
> org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@3.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
> at
> org.jboss.xnio@3.8.9.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class jakarta.servlet.http.MappingMatch
> cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping
> (jakarta.servlet.http.MappingMatch and
> jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping are in unnamed module of
> loader 'jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0' @2d839aa7)     at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.util.ServletRequestPathUtils$ServletRequestPath.getServletPathPrefix(ServletRequestPathUtils.java:258)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.util.ServletRequestPathUtils$ServletRequestPath.parse(ServletRequestPathUtils.java:250)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.util.ServletRequestPathUtils.parseAndCache(ServletRequestPathUtils.java:66)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:970)
> at
> deployment.myportal-1.0.0.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
> ... 87 more

**I had spent more time on this error. But no way...
Anyone know how to solve this issue?**

Comment: Are you including the servlet API in your deployment?